# Running Sum of 1d Array in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, data-structures

Hey guys I am learning data structure. I am trying to solve a problem of leetcode.

Given an array nums. We define a running sum of an array as `runningSum[i] = sum(nums[0]…nums[i])`.

Return the running sum of nums.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [1,3,6,10]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4].
```

I tried my solution and it working fine and I understand all stuff.

**My solution**

```
class Solution {
    fun runningSum(nums: IntArray): IntArray { 
        if (nums.size == 1) {
            return nums
        }
        for (index in 1..nums.size - 1) {
            nums[index] += nums[index - 1]
        }
        return nums
    }
}
```

**Complexity Analysis**

- **Time complexity:** O(n)O(n) where nn is the length of the input array. This is because we use a single loop that iterates over the
  entire array to calculate the running sum.
- **Space complexity:** O(1)O(1) since we don't use any additional space to find the running sum. Note that we do not take into
  consideration the space occupied by the output array.

Everything seems ok to me but I went to discuss section and I found one [fold solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/running-sum-of-1d-array/discuss/814874/Kotlin-Solution-with-fold). So my question is there

1. Is any complexity changes in this solution to my original solution?
2. If yes, can you please explain me in details?
3. Please explain me the use of [foldIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-indexed.html#:%7E:text=Accumulates%20value%20starting%20with%20initial,if%20the%20array%20is%20empty.) because I didn't get it correctly. I read the doc as well.

Many Thanks.

Comment: This is a digression and not an answer to your questions, but this task can be solved in Kotlin with simple: `list.runningReduce(Int::plus)`. Same tine complexity. I love this language :-D

Comment: Both your solution and the `foldIndexed` solution have O(N) time complexity. Your solution has O(1) space complexity while the other solution has O(N), because it returns a newly created array and leaves the original array unchanged. Sometimes, this is desirable, as it can be unexpected if the array you pass to a function gets changed.

Comment: Great guys thank you so much. I really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no change to the Time Complexity or Space Complexity when going from your solution to the other solution. So `foldIndexed` works the same way as `fold` with the key difference being that it also has an index. The programmer here chose `foldIndexed` because he was looking not for the sum at the end, but for the sum at each stage as it loops through the array, and he wanted to input them into the answers array. Knowing this, we can understand the essence of the code using `fold` instead. That'd look something like this:

```
fun runningSum(nums: IntArray): IntArray {
        val answers = IntArray(nums.size)

        nums.fold(0) {sum, element ->
            sum + element
        }

        return answers
    }
```

So going piece by piece, `0` is saying we're starting from the index `0` in the `nums` IntArray. `sum` is what is called an accumulator, which is basically a temporary variable within `.fold` which as the name suggests, accumulates as we continue to loop through the terms of the array. It accumulates based on the conditions we set for it within the function, which in this case is to increment by the value of the current element.

I hope that helped:)

Comment: i don't see `answers` being updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line (line-broke for clarity):

```
return IntArray(nums.size).also {
    // "it" is the IntArray just created
    nums.forEachIndexed { i, v ->
        it[i] = it.getOrElse(i - 1) { 0 } + v
    }
    // "it" will be returned here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow anyone.

**First Way:**

```
fun runningSum(nums: IntArray): IntArray{
    for ( index in 1 until nums.size){
        nums[index]+=nums[index-1]
    }
    return nums
}
```

**Second Way:**

```
fun runningSum(nums: IntArray): IntArray{
    var i = 0
    nums.fold(0) {sum, element ->
        nums[i++] = sum + element
        nums[i-1]
    }
    return nums
}
```

**Third Way**

```
fun runningSum(numbers: IntArray): IntArray {
    val numList = numbers.runningFold(0) { sum, num ->
        sum + num
    }.toMutableList()
    numList.removeFirst()
    return numList.toIntArray()
}
```